# VSPackage: Create toolbar dynamically with code

Tags: c#, dynamic, menu, toolbar, vspackage

Is it possible to define an *entire* toolbar for a vspackage dynamically (via code)?

I see it is possible with a menu (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx). Although toolbars "are" menus, unfortunately this example relies on a Menu of `type="MenuController",` so `type="Toolbar"` would not be possible anymore.

Of course could I could somehow get the `CommandBar`  and add `CommandBarButtons,` but I want to do it the VSPackage-way (not the old AddIn-way which I don't know how future proof it still is..).

My motivation for my undertaking is this: It is unbelievably annoying and time consuming to write any and all commands (+icons,etc) I want to add to the VSCT file. IF I could do everything in code, I could build a library for this annoying task and adding new commands would be a breeze!

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly discouraged to create the user interface of packages by code each time that the package is loaded instead of using .vsct because using .vsct the package is not required to load on VS startup, rather, it is loaded when a button is clicked (or a command is executed by any means). If your package creates the UI by code when loaded, you will need to mark it to load on VS startup (ProvideAutoload attribute with "No solution" value). If every package would do the same, VS startup would be very slow.

That said, see the [IVsProfferCommands4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproffercommands4.aspx) interface.